# SQLplus/JSP-INSERT Date of Birth as Date format

Tags: jsp, sqlplus

im updating a table on database with SQLPlus from a JSP page with name and Date of birth, how to insert the date of birth in Date format ? Please help me.

```
String dob=request.getParameter("DOB");
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date result = formater.parse(dob);
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table(DOB)VALUES('"+result+"')");
```

and my variable type in table is "Date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using sqlplus here. You're using JDBC.

And a date is a date. It's not a String. Sqlplus shows you the date as a string formatted in a certain way to make it readable, but you shouldn't  transform dates into strings to store them. Use a PreparedStatement:

```
String dob = request.getParameter("DOB");
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
java.util.Date dateOfBirth = formater.parse(dob);

String sql = "insert into table (dob) value (?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dateOfBirth.getTime());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

PreparedStatement should always be used to pass dynamic parameters to a SQL query. It's safer, more robust, and avoid SQL injection attacks.

Read the [JDBC tutorial about prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).